# Get latest positive result

Tags: r, dplyr

this is my data frame

```
 data <- data.frame(ID = c(174524, 175268, 176590),
     lab_info = c("RTPCR, RTPCR, RTPCR", "RTPCR, RTPCR, RTPCR, ANTIGEN, ANTIGEN", "RTPCR, RTPCR"),
     date_specimen_collected = c("09/25/2020, 01/05/2022, 05/03/2023", "07/09/2021, 10/27/2021, 05/04/2023, 07/07/2021, 07/09/2021", "07/18/2021, 05/04/2023"),
     lab_result = c("Positive, Positive, Positive", "Pending, Positive, Positive, Negative, Negative", "Positive, Positive"),
     date_result_received = c("01/01/1900, 01/07/2022, 05/04/2023", "01/01/1900, 10/28/2021, 05/04/2023, 07/07/2021, 07/09/2021", "07/18/2021, 05/05/2023"))
```

i want to get the latest positive
i get positive result but not latest date_specimen_collected

i used this code

```
FINAL_data <- data %>%
  select(ID, lab_info_type, date_specimen_collected, lab_result, date_result_received) %>%
  separate_rows(lab_info_type, lab_result, date_specimen_collected, date_result_received, sep = ",") %>%
  filter(lab_result == "Positive") %>%
  mutate(date_specimen_collected = as.Date(date_specimen_collected, "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
  arrange(desc(date_specimen_collected)) %>%
  group_by(ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there are whitespaces in your `lab_result` variable, the `filter()` is not necessarily catching all the cases you want.

I've added a `mutate()` line below that removes whitespaces across all character variables.

```
data %>%
  select(ID, lab_info, date_specimen_collected, lab_result, date_result_received) %>%
  separate_rows(lab_info, lab_result, date_specimen_collected, date_result_received, sep = ",") %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.character), stringr::str_trim)) %>% ## new line
  filter(lab_result == "Positive") %>%
  mutate(date_specimen_collected = as.Date(date_specimen_collected, "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
  arrange(desc(date_specimen_collected))
```